# Comparing data and updating table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have two tables: `voted_sites(USN,URL,vote,votefor)` and `sites(URL,status,upvotes,downvotes,id)`.

For a logged-in user I have update his reputation, stored in the repute field, based on the valid votes he has given, where voted_sites has what he has voted and the sites table is where the result of the site is (either ublocked or blocked).

If the user has also upvoted for unblock and the site table status is also unblock then I have to give increase his reputation by 5, and this should happen (traverse) through all the tuples and give a final reputation score for the user.

I've tried number of ways, but was unsuccessful in all attempts.
I didn't know how to do operations on 2 tables simultaneously when you can only connect to 1 table using `mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)`.

This is what I tried:

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<?php
$c=$_GET['param'];// users name
$d=$_GET['param1'];// usesrs id
$e=$_GET['param2'];//  users repute


// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","repute system");
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "ERROR ".mysqli_connect_error();
} 

$qwe = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM sites");
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM v_sites");
if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) 
    {
        
        if($d == $row['teacher_id'])
        {
            while ($raw = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qwe))
            {       
                 $rt = $row['votefor'];
                 $qt = $raw['status'];
                    if($row == $raw)
                    {
                        $er = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE teacher set repute = repute + '5'  where name == '$c' ");
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        $er = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE teacher set repute = repute - '5'  where name == '$c' ");
                    }
            }
            
      
       }
    }
}
 
?>
</html>
```

Comment: What you have implemented post this data

Comment: still not getting clear picture. Can elaborate points like what do expected and what is input going to be.

Comment: @CodeLord  first is my usage of mysqli_querys in nested if is posible? can i do that?

Comment: Can you use PDO for your operation.

Comment: Did you test your query into phpmyadmin or mysql cli

Comment: yes i did and i dont have any errors, neither its updating the teacher table

Comment: post your update query separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two equal signs in both your `where` clauses instead of one, as well as using string literals around the number you wish to increase it by.

```
UPDATE teacher set repute = repute + '5'  where name == '$c'
                                                     ^^
```

and

```
UPDATE teacher set repute = repute - '5'  where name == '$c'
                                                     ^^
```

**Those should read as:**

```
UPDATE teacher set repute = repute + 5  where name = '$c'
```

and

```
UPDATE teacher set repute = repute - 5  where name = '$c'
```

*Respectively.*

When testing, add `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to both `mysqli_query()` in order to see the syntax errors being made, if any during development.

- Sidenote: Make sure your `repute` column is indeed an `int` and of proper length.

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: hey I mailed you but didn't a get a reply back ! (on your site )

Comment: @razor You didn't confirm the email. There's a link you should have clicked. I use that in order to prevent my mailing to an accidental address ;-) Canada is very strict in regards to spam and I don't want to be dinged by a fine.

Comment: got it now ? i just sent one

Answer (score -1):

First Make sure that all(in your case both) tables are normalised.
Once you are sure of that, to work on two tables simultaneously you need to represent these tables as part of Relational db.
Then, you can most likely achieve operations on multiple tables simultaneously.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but mysql doesn't support Relational Databases.